# Why EIP-165 consider 0xffffffff value to be invalid id?

Tags: function-selector, eip-165

[EIP-165](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-165) aims to provide a way for a contract to communicate whether it has implemented a certain interface or not. The standard defines the interface identifier as the XOR of all function selectors in the interface.

The `0xffffffff` value is marked as an invariably invalid identifier. What is wrong with this number? Can't four leftmost bytes of Keccak-256 hash of the function signature (function selector is described in this way) have such a value?